# Como acionar pagina em caso de erro no web.xml JAVA

Tags: java

Preciso acionar uma página de erro em caso de exceções.
Coloquei esse código no `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>

    <location>/Casa da Borracha/erro.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type >
    <location>/Casa da Borracha/erro.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>

    <location>/Casa da Borracha/erro.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Mais tenho esse retorno:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found

Lembrando que minha página de erro esta na raiz do projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>

    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type >
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>

    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Se alguém precisar esta ai a resposta.